# iTunes 11 - Anyone seeing old reviews for old versions of their apps at the top

Tags: app-store, itunes

iTunes 11 was released yesterday.

**Anyone else noticing old reviews appearing on their app in the store?**

Apple have changed the sort order to Most Helpful from Most Positive.

But is also showing reviews that are a year out of date and for very old versions!

Sadly MOST HELPFUL requires user to tap WAS THIS HELPFUL? kind of like the LIKE button on FB.

But people only did this for my app when someone moaned about a bug that was actually caused by a bug... caused by Apple!

[image: App now showing 12 month old review for old version of the app]

Comment: I'm seeing this as well. Similar situation, an app that had only half of the features it has now and the top most review is for the initial release were the user was frustrated that the app didn't have the same features as the website (which we've had since 2005).

I'm not sure why someone downvoted you but I think this should be changed since it doesn't match the iOS and web version of the store.

Comment: Seems like this has been resolved.